# How to write an AHK script that uses a shortcut to close PowerShell?

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, powershell, automation, autohotkey, hotkeys

I've known that <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd> <kbd>C</kbd> could close PowerShell, but <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd> is already in use for me, I want to bind <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F4</kbd> to <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd> <kbd>C</kbd>, how to achieve that in AHK?

Comment: Doesn't a regular Alt+F4 close PowerShell already?

Comment: @user1686 Alt+F4 doesn't close PowerShell for me, seems to [require configuration](https://superuser.com/a/1388343/1023031).

Comment: Not familiar with AHK, but you can also type `Exit` to end a **PowerShell** console session.

Comment: @user1686 Windows 11 seems to support Alt+F4 closing PowerShell, are you using it by any chance?

Comment: @WenfangDu change to Windows Terminal instead. It's much better than the default conhost and will close when you press Alt+F4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following script enables using <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F4</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> to close PowerShell:

```
#IfWinActive ahk_exe powershell.exe
  !F4::
  ^d::WinClose
#IfWinActive
```